# Can't load data to tableview after it has been passed with delegation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, loaddata

I pass an array with delegation to tableviewcell, where I have tableview. Then I assign this array to an existing array so it should load to tableview. But it seems to be empty. Please, help!

```
func passArray(steps: [Step]) {

    self.array = steps
    print(steps)

}


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCell

    cell.textView.text = (array[indexPath.row] as! Step).text as String
    print(11, array)


    return cell
}
```

and here is where I have declared protocol

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    selectedRowIndex = indexPath


    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! IdeaTableViewCell

    editButton.frame = CGRect(x: cell.cellView.frame.size.width - 10, y: 15, width: 20, height: 20)
    editButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "change.png"), forState: .Normal)
    editButton.addTarget(self, action: "editButtonSegue", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.addSubview(editButton)

    cell.cellViewText.text = "\(ideas[indexPath.row].valueForKey("text") as! String). And it is cool because \(ideas[indexPath.row].valueForKey("why") as! String) and it has \((ideas[indexPath.row].valueForKey("steps") as! [Step]).count) steps"

    cell.cellViewTextBottomConstraint.constant = cell.tableView.contentSize.height + 16

    cell.cellViewText.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
    cell.tableView.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
    cell.tableView.hidden = false
    cell.tableView.beginUpdates()
    cell.tableView.endUpdates()
    delegate1?.passArray(ideas[indexPath.row].valueForKey("steps") as! [Step])
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()



}
```

Comment: can u post your code?

Comment: I am kinda new, so I don't know how to do it correctly

Comment: are you reloading the UITableview after you pass the array? like so: tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Study this and implement based on your logic https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/

Comment: self.table.reloadData() -> Use this method. it will load your data.

Comment: reloading data doesn't help

Comment: why are you using a delegate? you can just simply replace delegate1?.passArray(ideas[indexPath.row].valueForKey("steps") as! [Step]) with passArray()

Answer (score 1):

First of all check your array must not be empty and where you fill your array with values after that call the method

```
[self.yourTableViewName reloadData];
```

Comment: func passArray(steps: [Step]) {

    self.array = steps
    print(steps)

} in this method your array has values ...???

Comment: func passArray(steps: [Step]) {
        
        self.array = steps
        print(steps)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }   and it show that "unexpectedly found nil"

Comment: yep, it is printing its values

Comment: i think you should check your code properly all outlets are connected orr delegate called propely ...

Comment: when i load array like ["ffef","fife"] created in the IdeaTableViewCell it works fine

Comment: you call the delegates of tableview from storyboard orr anywhere in your code .....??? you must.

Comment: tableView.delegate = self , tableview.datasource = self  put it in viewdidLoad method

Comment: i have already done what you say. thank u for immediate response, but i figure out what to do. I simply just don't use delegation at all :0